# Can not receive ICE candidate

Tags: android, firebase, webrtc, webrtc-android

I have a WebRTC application and the amazing thing is that when I import com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore, I can receive ICE candidate. When I removed com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore, ICE gathering became abnormal.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.0'
```

I'll be stuck at GATHERING.

```
onIceGatheringChange : GATHERING
onIceConnectionChange : CHECKING
```

But in fact, I did not use the firestore related API at all. Does anyone know the reason? My guess is that there is something in the firestore that affects WebRTC.